# Passive Voice and Relative Clause sentences

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

1.the object to validate

2.the object to be validated

3.the object which will be validated

what are the differences between them? I thought all the sentences meant the same thing.

What subject do I need to know to understand sentences 1 and 2?

Are sentences 1 and 2 a different spelling of the third sentence?

Comment: These are all noun-phrases. This may seem pedantic but it is important. They can all mean the same but may not all be usable in any given sentance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practical meaning is much the same.

1. the object to validate  [contemporary, conversational]

2.the object to be validated [long-established, semi-formal]

3.the object which will be validated [prolix, formal]

Answer (score 0):

1.the object to validate

In this clause, there is an ellipse of someone who is to do the action.

2.the object to be validated

In this clause, “to be validated” is adjectival, modifying the noun.

3.the object which will be validated

In this relative clause, “which will be validated” is also adjectival, but it suggests that the sentence is incomplete. Something about that object needs to be said in order to finish this sentence.